# Concatenate values from XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml

I try to concatenate xml attributes, but it only takes the first pair, and then starts with the attributes from a new item. It will make sense when you read through the file.

```
import os, csv
from xml.etree import ElementTree


file_name = 'data.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('xml', file_name))
dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="") as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['fruitNumber', 'categoryNumber', 'Group', 'AttributeValueName'])



for d in dom.findall('//item'):
    part = d.find('.//item-number').text
    name = d.find('.//name').text
    value = d.find('.//value').text 
    writer.writerow([part, '' , '', name + ":" + value])
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<all>
<items>
<item>
<item-number>449</item-number>
<attributes>
<attribute>
<name>FRUIT</name>
<value>Lemon</value>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>COLOR</name>
<value>Yellow</value>
</attribute>
</attributes>
</item>
<item>
<item-number>223</item-number>
<attributes>
<attribute>
<name>FRUIT</name>
<value>Orange</value>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>COLOR</name>
<value>Orange</value>
</attribute>
</attributes>
</item>
</items>
</all>
```

Here is what I get:

```
fruitNumber categoryNumber  Group   AttributeValueName
449                                 FRUIT:Lemon
223                                 FRUIT:Orange
```

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
fruitNumber categoryNumber  Group   AttributeValueName
449                                 FRUIT:Lemon│COLOR:Yellow
223                                 FRUIT:Orange│COLOR:Orange
```

Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Comment: Why do you use `find()` instead of `findall()` if you want multiple matches? Your code is explicitly asking for only the first `name` and first `value` of each `item`.

Comment: If you want a row of output per `attribute` element, perhaps you should search for those at the top level of your loop, instead of finding `item`s first.

Comment: I use find() instead, because findall gives me an error message: list object has no attribute text

Comment: Yes, because you get a **list** of items, and need to retrieve the text from each one. You should be able to figure out how to iterate through a list and call `item.text` for each item in it without our help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only reading the first attribute of each item.  You need to additionally search the attributes under the item, collect them, then format them as you require when writing the row:

```
import os, csv
from xml.etree import ElementTree


file_name = 'data.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('xml', file_name))
dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="") as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['fruitNumber', 'categoryNumber', 'Group', 'AttributeValueName'])

    for d in dom.findall('.//item'):
        part = d.find('.//item-number').text
        L = []
        for a in d.findall('.//attribute'):
            name = a.find('.//name').text
            value = a.find('.//value').text
            L.append('{}:{}'.format(name,value))
        writer.writerow([part, '' , '', '|'.join(L)])
```

**Output**

> ```
> fruitNumber,categoryNumber,Group,AttributeValueName
> 449,,,FRUIT:Lemon|COLOR:Yellow
> 223,,,FRUIT:Orange|COLOR:Orange
> ```